# Decipher this regex

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I came back to a project I was working on several months ago, and one problem I figured out then was when I need to extract a certain part of a String. The String used both paranthesis and quotationmarks, so I couldn't split it like normal text.

Example of how the String might look:

> Word_Object("id"): preword:subword

Now say I wanted to only grab what's after the ("id"):, that is

> 'preword:subword'

I found that regex helped me out, and it took quite some time to find an EXAMPLE that was applicable for what I wanted. I had to settle for example, because I tried to find sources on how to learn about this incredibly complex system but I failed hard at that. The regex that solved it looks like this: `"Word_Object(\\(\"" + "id" + "\")\\): "`

I was content then that it seemed to work, but now when I got back to the project and tried it, I was trying to extract a word that used a underscore `_`and the underscore with the following word(s) was left out.

Example, splitting the text `Word_Object("id"): preword:subword_underscoreword`using the regex (using complete line now) `idSplit = subTemp.split("Word_Object(\\(\"" + "id" + "\")\\): ");`would simply return: `preword:subword`instead of the wanted `preword:subword_underscoreword`.

Did I somehow in this regex instruct it to ignore anything after the 2nd special-character (since it does accept :, but apparently _ breaks everything)?

Comment: Why split? Use `replaceAll` and substitute with empty string.

Comment: @stribizhev No, you use *groups* or *find* for extracting strings. `replaceAll` is about as logical as `split`.

Comment: This has a _surprisingly bad_ title for a _not too terrible_ question. It might be worth it to give your question a more relevant title.

Comment: I've voted to close this because of [a specific request by the author](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32095636/589259).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String[] split = "Word_Object(\"id\"): preword:subword_underscoreword".split("Word_Object(\\(\"" + "id" + "\")\\): ");
    System.out.println("split = " + split[1]);
}
```

Leads to

```
split = preword:subword_underscoreword
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments there's no need to use `.split()` it will give you an array of Strings and not the exact one, just use `.replace()` with an empty string and yopu will get the result you need :

```
        String str = "Word_Object(\"id\"): preword:subword_underscoreword";
        String str2 = str.replace("Word_Object(\"id\"): ", "");
```

This is **[a DEMO](https://ideone.com/tIyki8)** that will give you `preword:subword_underscoreword` in output.

Answer (score 0):

Since you might need to keep the `id` dynamic, here is a `replaceAll` solution:

```
String s = "Word_Object(\"id\"): preword:subword_underscoreword";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("Word_Object(\\(\"" + "id" + "\")\\):\\s*",""));
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/pZriFl)

Output: `preword:subword_underscoreword`

Comment: In case your input was just simplified, and this approach does not work for you, please feel free to drop a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You should match instead of replacing or splitting:

```
private static final Pattern PRE_SUB_WORD_EXTRACT = Pattern.compile("Word_Object\\(\"\\w+\"\\): (\\w+):(\\w+)");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "Word_Object(\"id\"): preword:subword_underscorewordusing";
    Matcher testMatcher = PRE_SUB_WORD_EXTRACT.matcher(test);
    if (!testMatcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Bollocks");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.printf("%s : %s%n", testMatcher.group(1), testMatcher.group(2));
}
```